# Regex not detect for htaccess Redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for essentially the opposite of this ...

```
^(.*)(?=\/nz\/)(.*)$
```

for some reason

```
^(.*)(?!=\/nz\/)(.*)$
```

is not working as I thought it would. I expected it to select like this

```
https://www.awebsite.com/fg/about-us/our-business -yes
https://www.awebsite.com/xx/about-us/our-business -yes
https://www.awebsite.com/pp/about-us/our-business -yes
https://www.awebsite.com/nz/about-us/our-business -no
/xx/about-us/our-business -yes
/pp/about-us/our-business -yes
/fg/about-us/our-business -yes
/nz/about-us/our-business -no
/about-us/our-business - no (is this also possible with 1 regex statement or do i need multiple rewritecond statements)
```

Any guidance on getting a solution that selects all lines that don't have /nz/ in them would be much appreciated.

*Side-note: this is for a rewrite/redirect in .htaccess.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex I think you should be using:

```
^((?!\/nz\/).)*$
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?!\/nz\/).` asserts that what follows each position in the string is not `/nz/`, and then it matches any character
- `((?!\/nz\/).)*` this expression is then matched any number of times, since the URL can be of arbitrary length

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

**Update:**

Here is a regex which should meet all of your requirements:

```
^(?!\/nz\/)\/\w\w(?!\/nz\/)\/((?!\/nz\/).)*$
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. could you please explain the use of double parenthesis at the start. Also this selection included the /about-us/our-business line. is there a way to not select that line as it doesnt start with /xx/ structure.

Comment: thanks this is now working with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\/[a-z][a-z]\/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^((?!\/nz\/).)*$
RewriteRule . https://www.awebsite.com/apage.html [L,R=301]`